# Vim regex search not working

Tags: regex, vim

Having these lines of code:

```
 window.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {                                                                                                                                         
     keydown(ev.key, ev.keyCode);                                                                                                                                                          
 });
```

And attempting substitution on the first one with the following regex:

```
:s/addEventListener('\v(\w*)', function(ev)/on\1 = ev =>/g
```

It says the following:

```
E486: Pattern not found: addEventListener('\v(\w*)', function(ev)
```

Why does that regex not match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of `\v` in your RE? Is this not the search pattern that you need?

```
/addEventListener('\(\w*\)', function(ev)/
```

(Also, please not that the original code is missing a closing ')'.)

Comment: Then I guess you should escape your ()-s in `function(ev)`, i.e. it should read `function\(ev\)`. And this may apply to the comma and apostrophe as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using very magic, `\v`, so you need to escape your other parentheses.

```
:s/addEventListener('\v(\w*)', function\(ev\)/on\1 = ev =>/g
```

It is often a good idea to use `\v` at the beginning of your pattern so escaping is consistent through the pattern.

```
:s/\vaddEventListener\('(\w*)', function\(ev\)/on\1 = ev =>/g
```

Maybe even not using `\v`, since you have many parens to match against (it's shorter too!).

```
:s/addEventListener('\(\w*\)', function(ev)/on\1 = ev =>/g
```

You may want to use [traces.vim](https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim) to preview substitutions or using [NeoVim's `'inccommand'`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'inccommand'). Also, newer versions (8.1.0271+) of Vim will match search patterns in side of `:s`, `:g`, and `:v` commands.

For more help see:

```
:h /\v
:h /magic
:h 'incsearch'
```